# Weird performance behavior of .NET dictionary insertion

Tags: c#, .net, performance, dictionary

I have two dictionaries with different value types: `Dictionary<int, string[]>` and `Dictionary<int, int[]>`. Suppose we generate random arrays in a loop and insert them to the dictionaries (in C#).

```cs
var d1 = new Dictionary<int, string[]>();
var d2 = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 40000000; i++)
{
    string[] sarr = new string[10];
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        sarr[j] = j.ToString();
    }
    int[] iarr = new int[10];
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        iarr[j] = j;
    }
    d1[i] = sarr; // (1)
    d2[i] = iarr; // (2)
}
sw.Stop();
```

Note the last two lines of the for loop. When I run the above code, it takes about 13.9 sec on my machine. Now, when I comment out only (1), then it takes about 13.7 sec. And if I comment out only (2), then it takes about 20 sec. In other words, by removing (2) it becomes much slower! I repeated this multiple times, and I can confirm that the behavior is consistent.

Can anyone please explain how this is even possible?

I did this experiment because I noticed that inserting `string[]` is slower than inserting `int[]` even though I am using the same key in the two dictionaries. I would like to know why inserting `string []` can be slower than inserting `int[]`, too.

So my quetion is twofold: (1) how come removing a line from the above code can make things slower, (2) why inserting `string[]` is slower than inserting `int[]`?

---

FYI, I am using the latest .NET 5 (5.0.103). I tried the code on both Windows and Linux, and the behavior was the same. I consistently see the same problem using either debug or release mode.

---

When I diff ILs of commented out version vs. original, the commented out version has no call to `set_Item` function of the dictionary as expected. Other things are more or less the same.

```
IL_0079: ldloc.1      // dictionary2
IL_007a: ldloc.3      // key
IL_007b: ldloc.s      numArray
IL_007d: callvirt     instance void class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<int32, int32[]>::set_Item(!0/*int32*/, !1/*int32[]*/)
IL_0082: nop
```

The above part was removed when I commented out (2) for example.

---

To help repro this problem, I created a simple repo with Benchmark.NET: https://github.com/sangkilc/TestDictionary. In this repo, I reduced the number of iterations (from 40M to 4M) because it takes too long.

On my machine the results are:

```
.NET Core SDK=5.0.103
  [Host]     : .NET Core 5.0.3 (CoreCLR 5.0.321.7212, CoreFX 5.0.321.7212), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 5.0.3 (CoreCLR 5.0.321.7212, CoreFX 5.0.321.7212), X64 RyuJIT


|   Method |    Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|--------- |--------:|---------:|---------:|
| TestBoth | 1.269 s | 0.0222 s | 0.0208 s |
|  TestOne | 1.381 s | 0.0257 s | 0.0241 s |
```

As per @TheodorZoulias's observation, if I modify `d2` to a 2D array, then the difference becomes more significant:

```
|   Method |    Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|--------- |--------:|---------:|---------:|
| TestBoth | 1.137 s | 0.0195 s | 0.0163 s |
|  TestOne | 1.373 s | 0.0246 s | 0.0345 s |
```

Comment: If you are running in release build (as opposed ot debug), then a lot of the code is going to be elided or transformed. For example, the `int` array is probably hoisted out of the loop

Comment: I understand your point, but do you think removing line (2) can prevent such an optimization?

Comment: I can confirm that I see consistent behavior in both Debug and Release mode.

Comment: Have you tried to look at the generated IL to find the differences?

Comment: Yes. the only difference I can see is the call to `set_Item` (i.e., the insertion).

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. Tried on Linqpad with .NET 5, both with optimizations on and off

Comment: This could be a memory consideration : if you don't retain your `iarr` or `sarr` by assigning their reference to a global `d1` or `d2`, then the garbage collector will try to reclaim the memory, which will save memory but will add some CPU load.

Comment: @XouDo You have that backwards.  It takes CPU resources to keep objects *alive* when the GC runs (to both traverse their memory for other referenced objects and also to copy their data), objects not alive when a collection happens consume no resources.

Comment: This mysterious behavior is even more exaggerated if you replace the `var d2 = new Dictionary<int, int[]>()` with a simple array: `var d2 = new int[40000000][]`

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks for the note. You are right, I can see significant difference by modifying `d2` to a 2D array.

Comment: @Servy that's.. a bit simplistic. Objects not alive force memory copying live objects after them to compress the GC memory back down. And the GC has to determine an object is not alive in the first place, which means doing an exhaustive search to one of its roots on every single handle. And on top of this, if an object stays alive long enough it forces a GC promotion, which means more memory copying.

Comment: @Blindy The GC is going to copy all live objects to a new section in memory on collection, not just shuffle objects up in memory based on the amount of space from freed objects.  And the GC doesn't search through dead objects to see if it can find a rooted reference, it searches through rooted references, copies everything that is thus alive, and just leaves the rest to die.  It's the *live* objects that consume resources traversing through references.

Comment: I think it totally makes sense if GC is the root cause of this problem. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: @Servy I may have a limited understanding of the GC, but it seems this perf issue is linked to garbage collection anyway (see weichch's post), so, what is your guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is not an answer, just wanted to show off some pictures*

I have the code compiled in *Release* for two of your scenarios:

- With both (1) and (2)
- With (1) only

Note that I removed `Stopwatch` related code, because we're only interested in `Dictionary`.

I have *dotTrace* on my machine, so I got some profiling results (line-by-line).

For the *both* scenario:

By Thread Tree:
[image]

By Methods:
[image]

For the *(1) only* scenario:

By Thread Tree:
[image]

By Methods:
[image]

Since you mentioned that the pattern is consistent, I ran the profiling only once.

From the results, we could tell functions related to `Dictionary` are not the main contributors to the so called "weird performance behavior", GC *probably* is.

Comment: The performance breakdown you showed clearly support the GC problem; it takes about ~7%. I think the problem is clearly due to GC after seeing lots of comments from people, and I will just select this as an answer. One more note: the weird behavior disappears if I reduce the number of loop iterations. So less garbage, less performance degradation. Thank you!